# iOS 6 throwing error when using Google's OAuth

Tags: iphone, types, oauth, ios6, xcode4.5

Over the weekend I upgraded my version of xcode to the newest version, and the latest SDK (iOS 6.0). This morning when I went into it to take a look at how our app had faired in the transition, I noticed something strange. I get errors such as:

uknown type `'GDataOAuthentication'` for

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) GDataOAuthAuthentication *authentication;
```

in `GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.h`

This was working just fine under the last version. Any ideas as to what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the Valid Architecture from arm7s to arm7. Arm7s is the new architecture for iPhone 5 and could be the issue causing GData  as well as other libraries.

Also is this running on the simulator or phone? Mine compiles on the phone not on simulator so still an issue.